# Modelagem de Software

Tags: java, modelagem, engenharia-de-software, uml

Um software que tem a opção de cadastro de projetos e que cada projeto tem seus dias úteis(dias de trabalho) específicos, que por padrão é de segunda a sexta, porém podem ser alterados pelos gestores do projeto.

A dúvida é a respeito da implementação dessa relação entre cada projeto e seus dias uteis. Eu pensei em criar vários atributos booleanos representando os dias da semana marcados com true ou false se são dias de trabalho ou não. Porém, acho muito "hard code". Qual seria a melhor implementação para a situação? Como associar cada projeto aos seus dias de trabalho?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De uma forma pode parecer "hardcore" a ideia de inserir 7 colunas como booleanos, mas **analisando as outras possibilidades** como por exemplo utilizar somente uma coluna string ou de algum tipo numérico para "decodificar" a informação no seu código (não sei se chegou a pensar em outras possibilidades para o seu caso), **já seria mais custoso que validar 7 colunas booleanas**, a princípio vem a ser a melhor forma a ser tratado nesse caso.

Usar timestamp, também está fora de cogitação nesse caso, a princípio é desnecessário.

Ainda reforço a ideia de manter as 7 colunas, pois temos certeza que o número de dias em uma semana não irá se alterar (pelo menos não facilmente).

Sem dizer que você já irá ter o resultado em sua aplicação direto pela Query, sem necessidade de fazer outras análises adicionais (necessária em outras modelagens para esse caso)